# Unable to load picture or PDF file using subfiles and XeLaTeX

Tags: graphics, xetex, color, subfiles

I am trying to include diagrams in the tex file using `.pdf_tex` files using `xelatex`.

`main.tex`:

```latex
% Preamble
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[multidot]{grffile}

% Do not use apacite and natlib at the same time
%\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib} % Use for numbered reference
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
%\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

% Section formatting
\usepackage{titlesec}
% Custom subsubsubsection
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]

\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}} % optional; useful if paragraphs are to be numbered

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{6}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{4em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}}
\makeatother
% Uses alphabets instead of numbers for the subsubsubsection
\def\thesubsubsubsection{\alph{subsubsubsection}}


% Subfiles with biblio for multiple tex files
\usepackage{subfiles}
\providecommand{\main}{.}
\def\biblio{\bibliography{main}\bibliographystyle{apalike}}
\def\biblio{}

% Citation formatting !!! MUST BE LAST
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens,spaces}{url}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Page Settings
\geometry{a4paper, margin = 1in}

% Document
\begin{document}


  \subfile{methodology/methodology.tex}


\end{document}
```

The `methodology.tex` file containing the `.pdf_tex` call:

```latex
% Preamble
\providecommand{\main}{..}
\documentclass[\main/main.tex]{subfiles}

% Packages

% Document
\begin{document}


  \begin{figure}
  \def\svgwidth{\linewidth}
  \input{\main/assets/images/xor_data_embedding.pdf_tex}
  \caption{Diagram}
  \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Was hoping for a output like this [image] but alas.

But I can not seem to figure out how to solve the issue. It says it can't load the file but I can't seem to figure out why.

Terminal Output:

```
line 56: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=1]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 56: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...nitlength,page=1]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 56: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=1]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 58: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=2]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 58: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...nitlength,page=2]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 58: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=2]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 60: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=3]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 60: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...nitlength,page=3]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 60: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=3]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 62: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=4]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 62: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...nitlength,page=4]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 62: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=4]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 64: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=5]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 64: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...nitlength,page=5]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 64: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=5]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 66: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=6]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 66: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...nitlength,page=6]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 66: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=6]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 68: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=7]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 68: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...nitlength,page=7]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 68: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=7]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 70: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=8]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 70: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...nitlength,page=8]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 70: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=8]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 72: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=9]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 72: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...nitlength,page=9]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 72: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...nitlength,page=9]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 74: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=10]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 74: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...itlength,page=10]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 74: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=10]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 76: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=11]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 76: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...itlength,page=11]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 76: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=11]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 78: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=12]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 78: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...itlength,page=12]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 78: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=12]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 80: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=13]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 80: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...itlength,page=13]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 80: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=13]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 82: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=14]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 82: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...itlength,page=14]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 82: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=14]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 84: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=15]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 84: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...itlength,page=15]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 84: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=15]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 86: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=16]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 86: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...itlength,page=16]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 86: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=16]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 88: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=17]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 88: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...itlength,page=17]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 88: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=17]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 90: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=18]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 90: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...itlength,page=18]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 90: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=18]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 92: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=19]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 92: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...itlength,page=19]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 92: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=19]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 94: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=20]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 94: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...itlength,page=20]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 94: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=20]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 96: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=21]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 96: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...itlength,page=21]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 96: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=21]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 98: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=22]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 98: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...itlength,page=22]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 98: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...itlength,page=22]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 100: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=23]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 100: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...tlength,page=23]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 100: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=23]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 102: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=24]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 102: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...tlength,page=24]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 102: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=24]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 104: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=25]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 104: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...tlength,page=25]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 104: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=25]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 106: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=26]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 106: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...tlength,page=26]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 106: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=26]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 108: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=27]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 108: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...tlength,page=27]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 108: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=27]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 110: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=28]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 110: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...tlength,page=28]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 110: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=28]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 112: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=29]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 112: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...tlength,page=29]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 112: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=29]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 114: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=30]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 114: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...tlength,page=30]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 114: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=30]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 116: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=31]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 116: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...tlength,page=31]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 116: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=31]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 118: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=32]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 118: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...tlength,page=32]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 118: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=32]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 120: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=33]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 120: Package graphics Error: Division by 0. ...tlength,page=33]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 120: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=33]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
line 122: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'xor_data_embedding.pdf'. ...tlength,page=34]{xor_data_embedding.pdf}}
: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.
: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.
line 56: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 58: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 60: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 62: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 64: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 66: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 68: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 70: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 72: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 74: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 76: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 78: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 80: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 82: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 84: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 86: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 88: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 90: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 92: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 94: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 96: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 98: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 100: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 102: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 104: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 106: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 108: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 110: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 112: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 114: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 116: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 118: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 120: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
line 122: File `xor_data_embedding.pdf' not found
```

I do not think I missed placing the `xor_data_embedding.*` files in their correct folders.

Folder Structure:

```
.
|
+---out
|       main.aux
|       main.bbl
|       main.blg
|       main.log
|       main.pdf
\---src
    |   main.tex
    +---assets
    |   \---images
    |           xor_data_embedding.pdf
    |           xor_data_embedding.pdf_tex
    \---methodology
            methodology.tex
```

The diagram was made using Adobe Illustrator and exported into a `.svg`, then converted into `.pdf_tex` using Inkscape. The files are [here](https://fileleaks.com/8HMDzWjVEK/Diagrams.zip) if required.

Any guidance is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to define `graphicspath` and `declaregrahpichextension{pdf}`? Sometimes it has happened to me that if you do not do that, the PDF_TEX file does not found its corresponding PDF file, which seems to be the error in your log

Comment: This question does not involve `amsmath`, so I've removed that tag.

Comment: Add  `\graphicspath{{./assets/images/}}`  before `\begin{document}` in `main.tex`.

Comment: @Simon Dispa It is working but can you explain why it doesn't find the path when specified directly?

Comment: I added an explanation, expecting to clarify your doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why it doesn't find the path when specified directly?**

Because there are two different paths: (a) to  the image `xor_data_embedding.pdf` as seen from `main.tex`, and (b) to the file  `xor_data_embedding.pdf_tex`.

`methodology.tex` inputs the  file `../assets/images/xor_data_embedding.pdf_tex` which is able to happily  produce a figure as output using `xor_data_embedding.pdf` sitting its same directory.

There are three possible cases to test:

(1) Run `methodology.tex` commenting `\subfile{methodology/methodology.tex}` in `main.tex`

It will generate `methodology.pdf` in its own directory using

`.././assets/images//xor_data_embedding.pdf`'
as source.

It does not need `\graphicspath{{./assets/images/}}` in main.

(2)  Run `main.tex` , now including `\subfile{methodology/methodology.tex}`

The compiler will run twice, but this is not related with paths or subfiles.

Adding `\graphicspath{{./assets/images/}}` points `main.tex` to the figure and it will generate `main.pdf` in the root directory now using  `./assets/images//xor_data_embedding.pdf` as source.

(3)  Run `methodology.tex`,  including  `\subfile{methodology/methodology.tex}` in `main.tex`,  deleting before all files from the root directory except `main.tex`.

As before there will be two process with the same result of (2). (only one run if `main.aux` was kept.)

This is a MWE of `main.tex`

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}   
\geometry{a4paper, margin = 1in}

\graphicspath{{./assets/images/}} % full path to image xor_data_embedding.pdf   
% Document
\begin{document}    
    
\subfile{methodology/methodology.tex}   
    
\end{document}
```

This is `methodology.tex`

```
\providecommand{\fullpathtofile}{../assets/images/} %% full path to file xor_data_embedding.pdf_tex

\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

% Document
\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{figure}
        \def\svgwidth{\linewidth}
    \input{\fullpathtofile/xor_data_embedding.pdf_tex}
        \caption{Diagram}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document
```

Note that `\fullpathtofile` points to the file `xor_data_embedding.pdf_tex` not to `xor_data_embedding.pdf`

Comment: So, if I have a say another folder in `assets`, or anywhere, called `diagrams`. I would have to add `\graphicspath{{./assets/diagrams/}}` in the `main.tex` and repeat for as many folders I have? Wouldn't that count as repetition or is that the recommended way to do things? Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @Rashiq Like `\graphicspath{{<path1>}{<path2>}{<path3>}}`  with nothing in between the braces.