# how to handle subfiles picture in latex

Tags: subfiles

Now I am using subfile to compile document independent, I want to insert a picture in the sub document like this:

```
\documentclass[../../../dolphin-book-2020.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\subsection{GitHub Slow}

balabalabala.......


\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{githubspeedup}
    \caption{GitHub Speed Up}
    \label{fig:githubspeedup}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

when I compile using this command in macOS Catalina 10.15 :

```
 /Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk -pdfxe -pvc -xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode ./github-slow.tex
```

show this error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)

Package fontspec Warning: Font "FandolFang-Regular" does not contain requested
(fontspec)                Script "CJK".


! LaTeX Error: File `githubspeedup' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.31 ^^I\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{githubspeedup}

[1] (./github-slow.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on github-slow.xdv (1 page, 28900 bytes).
Transcript written on github-slow.log.
=== TeX engine is 'XeTeX'
Latexmk: Index file 'github-slow.idx' was written
Latexmk: Missing input file: 'githubspeedup' from line
  '! LaTeX Error: File `githubspeedup' not found.'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'github-slow.xdv'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Latexmk: Failure to make the files correctly
    ==> You will need to change a source file before I do another run <==
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  xelatex: Command for 'xelatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'github-slow.log' for details

=== Watching for updated files. Use ctrl/C to stop ...
^CLatexmk: User typed ctrl/C or ctrl/break.  I'll finish.
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  xelatex: Command for 'xelatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'github-slow.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
```

what should I do to make it work? I have already added picture path in the main file `dolphin-book-2020.tex` like this(all the picture store in the folder and no picture store in sub folder):

```
\graphicspath{{./Pictures/}}
```

and this is the file structure:

[image]

I have tried define picture path in `dolphin-book-2020.tex` like this:

```
\graphicspath{{../../../Pictures/}{../../Pictures/}{../Pictures/}{./Pictures/}}
```

this is the folder nested structure:

[image]

I also tried to write all possible path of picture:

```
\graphicspath{
    {Pictures/}
    {../../../Pictures/}
    {../../Pictures/}
    {image/}
    {/Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/dolphin-book-2020/Pictures}
}
```

still could not found file.

Comment: Please see this answer before asking a similar question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the search path to the image in **the main document**.

[image: t]

Assuming that:

(1) `dolphin-book-2020.tex` is in the directory `BOOK`

(2) The chapters are in `BOOK/chapters`

(3) The images are in  `BOOK/chapters/images`  and the sub-directory `images` contain `githubspeedup.jpg`

(4) The subsections are in `BOOK/chapters/subsections` and that sub-directory contains `GitHubSlow.tex`

you will get

[image: a]

compiling  `dolphin-book-2020.tex`  or `GitHubSlow.tex`

The searching  path from the main file, and from the subfile, to the image was added as

`\graphicspath{{./chapters/images/}}} %  path to image githubspeedup.jpg`

**in the main file** `dolphin-book-2020.tex` <<<<<<<<

Multiple searching paths might be added as

`\graphicspath{{<path1>}{<path2>}{<path3>}}}`

This is `dolphin-book-2020.tex`

```
 %% dolphin-book-2020.tex in its own directory BOOK

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subfiles} 

\graphicspath{{./chapters/images/}} %  path from here to image githubspeedup.jpg   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added

\begin{document}
    
\subfile{./chapters/subsections/GitHubSlow}  % subsection file in  BOOK/chapters/subsections subdirectory
    
\end{document}
```

This is `GitHubSlow.tex` in the subsections sub-directory

```
% GitHubSlow.tex in BOOK/chapters/subsections

\documentclass[../../dolphin-book-2020.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
    
    \subsection{GitHub Slow}
    
    balabalabala....... 
    
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{githubspeedup}
        \caption{GitHub Speed Up}
        \label{fig:githubspeedup}
    \end{figure}    
    
\end{document}
```

Related: [Unable to load picture or PDF file using subfiles and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/590273/unable-to-load-picture-or-pdf-file-using-subfiles-and-xelatex/590695#590695)

Comment: +1: Nice file tree

Comment: I tried your way but still not work. @Simon Dispa

Answer (score 0):

On the subfiles add picture path like this:

```
\documentclass[../../../dolphin-book-2020.tex]{subfiles}
\usepackage{graphics} % add package
\graphicspath{
    {../../../Pictures/}
} % add picture path

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{codesign}
    \caption{fastlane}
    \label{fig:codesign}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\graphicspath{    {../../../Pictures/}}  `  should go in the main file, not in the subfile!!

Comment: main file did not work, subfile works fine@SimonDispa

Comment: It is better to have a single preamble in the main file to be used by all  subfiles. Better maintenance and less confusing.  `\usepackage{graphics} `  and the path should go in `dolphin-book-2020.tex` preamble, with the path pointing to the image as seen from there.