# how to handle figure when using subfiles in latex document

Tags: xetex

when I am using subfiles in my tex document:

```
\subfile{./chapter-2020-02/chapter-2020-02}
```

when the subfile using figure like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{mavenauthpassword}
    \caption{Maven}
    \label{fig:mavenauthpassword}
\end{figure}
```

shows this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `mavenauthpassword.tex' not found.
```

what should I do to using figure correctly when using subfiles in latex document?

Comment: Please see my answer to your previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591088/how-to-handle-subfiles-picture-in-latex

Comment: You do not tell us in which directory the image actually is. If you do not specify any `\graphicspath`, then LaTeX will search the image `mavenauthpassword....` in the same directory as `chapter-2020-02.tex`.